# Is autoencoder for anomaly detection a transfer learning?

Tags: classification, autoencoders, anomaly-detection, transfer-learning

I am doing a binary classification with unsupervised learning. I learn an autoencoder on samples from class0 and then predict samples from both class0 and class1. Then I classify sample according to reconstruction error (small = class0, high = class1). Is this a transfer learning? I mean, the main task is to learn representation of class0, which is then transfered to decide between class0 and class1. If no, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think many would call this transfer learning, or that it is very useful to do so. The decision for class1 is just 'not class0'. Or seen based on a distance function or probability, class1 = score > threshold, which is equivalent to class0 = score < threshold, ie only the sign changed.

Modeling normality instead of using both classes to create a decision boundary is sometimes seen as a key distinction between anomaly detection and binary classification. It is usually preferred in the hopes that it will generalize better to new kind of anomalies - which are neither like class0 nor like known class1.

In transfer learning there is an expectation that the dataset (and possibly the task or learning setup) changes between the pretext task and the downstream task. And that one can apply techniques such as fine tuning to better adapt to the downstream case. This is not the case for anomaly detection, in general.